# I'm getting an error when I'm tring to include slf4j in a OSGi bundle

Tags: java, osgi, slf4j

I have a OSGi bundle and I want use in this bundle slf4j package so I've added into `manifest.mf`(located in `META-INF`) this:

```
Import-Package: org.slf4j;version="[1.7.7,2)"
```

But I'm getting this error:

> This inspections reports usage of classes from packages not
>   accessible inside the OSGi context - i.e. not imported neither
>   implicitly nor via manifest file. Asking for such a classes may cause
>   "class not found" exceptions at runtime. The inspection is only
>   effective for modules with OSGi facet set to use existing manifest
>   file.

I'm using intellijidea 13.1

Comment: Doesn't sound like an error, but just a warning that IntelliJ can't do certain inspections. Does your program not compile or run? If not, then what is the actual compile error or runtime error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OSGi mode Idea introspects the jars (bundles) you use. Probably the slf4j api you use is not an OSGi bundle. So idea does not find a bundle that offers the package you import. As in the runtime you probably use a different bundle like pax-logging this warning can be ignored.